# Why $(shell ls) is expanded at the start of the makefile task?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have the following code:

```
foo:

    touch foo

    $(foreach f, $(shell ls | grep foo), \
        echo $f; \
    )
```

it will not list the file `foo` created by the `touch foo` above, will list if the `foo` file already exists before the task starts, like this:

```
$ make foo # first time call, file 'foo' doesn't exists yet

$ make foo # second time call, file 'foo' already exists
  foo
```

Is there a way to evaluate the `ls` after all the commands above are executed?

Comment: The entire Makefile is rendered upon execution of any target, AFAIK, so any `$()` block therefore is executed before the content of the target

Comment: Note that making programmatic use of `ls` [should be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) regardless.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, the link's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Make works. The Makefile is parsed and any Makefile functions are called, *then* one or more recipes are evaluated.

Is there a reason you're not simply using a shell loop?

```
foo:
    touch foo
    for f in *foo*; do \
         echo "$$f"; \
    done
```

Notice how the dollar sign needs to be doubled to escape it from being evaluated by `make`, and also how shell variables should generally be double-quoted unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value.

On the other hand, a more "make-ish" approach is to explicitly document any dependencies.

```
.PHONY: all
all: foo
     printf '%s\n' $^
foo:
     touch $@
```

Now `all` depends on `foo`, so Make knows it must create `foo` before it can perform the `all` recipe if `foo` doesn't exist, or is out of date in relation to its own dependencies (of which of course there are currently none).

The `make` variable `$^` refers to the dependencies of the current target, and `$@` expands to the current recipe target. The `printf` shell script is just a more economical way to print one thing per line without a loop.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful! I was using foreach because I read that foreach is a builtin makefile function but I didn't know the difference how they're treated differently. And I didn't use the dependency way because I'm using a regexp to match files generated by another program and move them all to a specific directory, the file don't have fixed names so I just put the generating and moving parts inside a single recipe, not sure if there's better way to do this

Comment: Hopefully shell wildcards are enough to select the files you need. Then you don't need a loop for `mv` either; just `mv *wildcard1* *wc2* *three* *etc* directory/`

Comment: Yes the shell wildcards works in this case, thank you